# Applying Dynamic Styles to Skins in Flex

Tags: apache-flex, styling, skinning

I have a skin for a scrollbar thumb that I want to be able to style or set properties dynamically.

```
<mx:Panel   
    verticalScrollBarStyleName="verticalScrollBarNoArrows">
</mx:Panel>
```

style.css

```
.verticalScrollBarNoArrows
{
    upArrowSkin:      ClassReference(null);
    downArrowSkin:  ClassReference(null);

    trackSkin:      ClassReference(null);
    thumbSkin:      ClassReference("skins.ScrollBarThumb"); 
}
```

ScrollBarThumb.as (snippet)

```
public class ScrollBarThumb extends Border
{
    [Bindable]
    private var cornerRadius:Number = 2;

    [Bindable]
    private var backgroundColor:uint = 0x222222;

    [Bindable]
    private var xOffset:int = -3;
```

I want to be able to set these properties in the skin so the skin can be styled differently for each component that uses it.

How do you suggest I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should usually set styles on a skin as styles not as properties:

```
[Style(name="cornerRadius", type="Number", format="Length", inherit="yes")]
```

Then in `updateDisplayList` you can call `getStyle("cornerRadius")` when you draw the skin.